# RAID Controller reports warning "Backup DCB read error detected"

Tags: raid, 3ware

As mentioned in the title, my 3ware RAID Controller 9650SE-16ML reports the following warning:

```
Jul 26, 2017 09:16:33PM - Controller 0
WARNING - Backup DCB read error detected: port=15(null)
```

This warning is sent once on every server bootup.
The status of the drive on port 15 is "OK". It seems to work correctly. The other drivers are working as well.
The status of the RAID units on that controller are "OK", none is degraded.
Even after verifying the affected unit, the warning still appears.

What going on here? What can i do to fix that?

Edit:
Only useful thing i could find was this:

> The controller has detected a latent error in the backup Disk Configuration Block (DCB).
>
> The 3ware RAID controller checks the backup DCB, even when the primary
>   DCB is OK. If an error is found, the controller will attempt to
>   correct the error by reading the primary copy. If the primary copy is
>   valid, the backup DCB will be rewritten to rectify the errors.
>
> Action: AMCC recommends verifying the unit.
>
> Source: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Komplette_%C3%9Cbersicht_aller_3ware_Ereignismeldungen

Verifying the unit did not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely certain that the unit that is holding the backup DCB isn't going bad? You may wish to perform a block-by-block read/write test or SMART check.

If it is possible, try rotating the configuration of the drives such that the suspected unit is not used for either DCB.

Comment: You were right. A SMART check revealed the drive is broken. Thanks!